# Creating regular time series from irregular time series (with data changes only)

Tags: time-series, interpolation, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I am using data from a sensor, that only sends the value if it has changed with the timestamp of the data change. 
The result looks for example like this:

```
timestamp   temperature
10:17:66    31
10:18:10    30
10:29:30    31
12:51:31    32
```

For some analysis, especially when I want to compare two time series I need equal timeintervals. For that purpose I would define a timeinterval like 10 minutes.
I am not sure what is the best approach to calculate the values in that case in 10 minutes intervals.

Let's say I want to calculate the value for 10:30:00. Between 10:20 and 10:30 most of the time the temperature was 30, so I surely have to weight that value higher than 31, which was present only for the last 30s. Is the best approach to calculate the integral here?

Is there some R function, that can calculate regular time intervals in that way for me? I found the "approx.irts", which interpolates the values, but this is not the right way here I guess as I don't have missing values or times here?

Comment: One approach would be to reconsider the assumption that you need to perform this interpolation in order to compare time series. For many forms of comparison that would be computationally inefficient or even inappropriate. An alternative would be to construct a function `f(time, series)` that returns the value of `series` at the time `time`, then use that to compare the two series at any set of times you like (such as when one or both of them changed values, or at a random sample of times, or even a regular grid of times).

Comment: I would need the regular time intervals to perform correlations (cross and auto) or arima models (and other time series analytics). 
But I think the important thing here is that I don't want to interpolate or estimate a value, because I have all data changes available. It's a fact that at 10:30:00 it had 31 degrees. I just need a value that represents the variable best at a certain time. My idea was to use the "average" or integral from 10:20:00 to 10:30:00 to do that, but not sure if that's the best solution.

Comment: I used "interpolate" in the strong sense of *look up the actual value at the time*: no estimation is needed. For instance,  with the data in your example if the time of 11:00 is supplied, it need merely look up the current sensor reading to discover it is 31. The applicability of Arima models for such data should be questioned, especially if you do intend to interpolate among the sensor value, for then the correlation structure will reflect a mixture of the true structure and an artificial component introduced by your interpolation procedure. But with enough data it might not matter... .

Comment: So at 1030 you would take the 31. Why wouldnt it be better to take the mean value from the last 10minutes and give the value which was valid for a longer time period more weight.

Comment: If I want to calculate the average for the last 10 minutes, what would be the right approach?